# How to prove the following trigonometric equation?

Tags: trigonometry

How to prove that 
$\tan5x.\tan3x.\tan 2x = \tan5x - \tan3x -  \tan2x$

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $3x+2x=5x$

Take $\tan$ on both sides
$$\tan(3x+2x)=\tan5x$$
Use the trig formula $\tan(A+B)$ and we get
$$\dfrac{\tan3x+\tan2x}{1-\tan3x\tan2x}=\tan5x$$
$$\tan3x+\tan2x=\tan5x(1-\tan3x\cdot\tan2x)$$
$$\tan3x+\tan2x=\tan5x-\tan2x\cdot\tan3x\cdot\tan5x$$
Therefore, $$\tan5x\cdot\tan3x\cdot\tan 2x = \tan5x - \tan3x - \tan 2x$$

Comment: about to finish(+1) :)

Comment: Also, it's $\tan(2x)$ instead of $\tan(x)$

Comment: @Ak19 Thanks, fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

$\tan(A+B+C)=\dfrac{\tan A+\tan B+\tan C-\tan A\tan B\tan C}{\cdots}$

If $A+B+C=n\pi,\tan(A+B+C)=?$

If all the tangent ratios are finite,

$\tan A+\tan B+\tan C=\tan A\tan B\tan C$

Here $A,B,C$ can be chosen

from $\{5x,-3x,-2x\}$

or from $\{-5x,3x,2x\}$

Use $\tan(-y)=-\tan y$